# Is there a way to delete a character that has just been written using Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, console.writeline

Is there any way to delete the last character from the console, i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine("List: apple,pear,");
// Somehow delete the last ',' character from the console.
Console.WriteLine(".");
// Now the console contains "List: apple,pear."
```

Sure, I could create a string first then print that to the console, but I'm just curious to see if I can delete characters directly from the console.

Comment: By the way, if you use the `string.Join` method, then you won’t have to worry about that extra comma at the end. `Console.WriteLine("List: " + string.Join(",", fruitArray) + ".");`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

"\b" is ASCII backspace.  Print it to back up one char.

```
Console.Write("Abc");
Console.Write("\b");
Console.Write("Def");
```

outputs "AbDef";

As pointed out by Contango and Sammi, there are times where overwriting with a space is required:

```
Console.Write("\b \b");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I appreciate your answer - its one of those problems that difficult to find an answer to as its difficult to find search terms that are not ambiguous.

Comment: Just realized that if you do a newline straight after the \b, it doesn't work - you have to add a space to "overwrite" the rogue character. The \b controls the cursor, its more like an arrow key left than a backspace.

Comment: Actually '\b' will only work in current line. You are not able to override characters in previous line.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows 11 with Windows terminal, sadly...

Answer (score 55):

`Console.Write("\b \b");` is probably what you want. It deletes the last char and moves the caret back.

The `\b` backspace escape character only moves the caret back. It doesn't remove the last char. So `Console.Write("\b");` only moves the caret one back, leaving the last character still visible.

`Console.Write("\b \b");` however, first moves the caret back, then writes a whitespace character that overwrites the last char and moves the caret forward again. So we write a second `\b` to move the caret back again. Now we have done what the backspace button normally does.

Answer (score 20):

This will do the trick if you use `Write` instead of `WriteLine`.

```
Console.Write("List: apple,pear,");
Console.Write("\b");  // backspace character
Console.WriteLine(".");
```

But you actually have lots of control over the console. You can write to any location you wish. Just use the `Console.SetCursorPosition(int, int)` method.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the Console.SetCursorPosition method.

Answer (score 8):

To delete a character on the console use

```
Console.Write("\x1B[1D"); // Move the cursor one unit to the left
Console.Write("\x1B[1P"); // Delete the character
```

This will **properly** delete the character before the cursor and move all following characters back.
Using the statement below you will only replace the character before the cursor by a white space and not actually *remove* it.

```
Console.Write("\b \b");
```

My proposed solution should work in some **other programming languages as well**, since it is using ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting you up as this is a good alternative answer. I do think that both answers are equivalent, as deleting a character, and overwriting it with a space, are probably the same thing from the users point of view.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when debugging at least.

The "\b \b" probably works better than 'SysCon.SetCursorPosition(SysCon.CursorLeft - bkspcLen, SysCon.CursorTop);', as 'SetCursorPosition' can't be (stdout) redirected to a file, but "\b \b" still looks unpleasing when redirected to a file.

I.E.  You might be best avoiding the need altogether.

Comment: @DennisVM-D2i Not sure what you mean. My answer does not include any call to 'SetCursorPosition'. Also the question asked was about deleting characters on the console and not in a file.

Comment: @nullmn I was referring to the other in-built alternative - 'SetCursorPosition', and referring to a slight extension of what's been asked.  Your solution works better than 'SetCursorPosition', but the use-case as a whole does not seem so great *if* you also need to redirect the stdout (Standard Output) to a file - one thing to be aware of.  I wonder .. if 'Console.Write("\r");' works any better (?).

Answer (score 6):

if you want to delete only one char you can use:

`Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);` and `Console.Write()` again.

if you want to delete more than one char, like an automation, you can store the current `Console.CursorLeft` in a variable and use that value in `Console.SetCursorPosition(--variablename, Console.CursorTop)` in a loop to delete many chars you want!

Comment: This answer is better than playing with ANSI chars. It is better readable.

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions works great unless you're iterating through a for or foreach loop. In that situation you must use a different approach, like

```
 Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
 Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

It does, however work well also for a string join.

Examples:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write(myList[i] + ", ");
}

Console.WriteLine("\b\b"); //this will not work.

foreach (int item in myList)
{
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
}

//this will work:
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 2, Console.CursorTop);
Console.WriteLine("  ");

//you can also do this, btw
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myList) + "\b\b");
```

Comment: This isn't very safe... If you're on a new line (Console.CursorLeft = 0), this will throw an exception.

Comment: I guess specifically, you need something more like Console.SetCursorPosition((Console.CursorLeft - 2 + Console.WindowWidth) % Console.WindowWidth, Console.CursorLeft - 2 <= 0 ? Console.CursorTop - 1 : Console.CursorTop);

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep on writing into the same line,
overwriting the old line content, not creating a new line,
you can also simply write:

```
Console.Write("\r"); //CR = 'carriage return' char, moves cursor back to 1st pos in current line, but doesn't add a new one which would do '\n'
Console.Write("{0} Seconds...)", secondsLeft);
```

So if you want to count down from 10 to 0 then continue if would go like:

```
for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--)
{
    Console.Write("\r");
    Console.Write("{0} seconds left...{1}", i, i == 1 ? "\n" : "");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: This helped me! I prefer this method over \b as it feels more natural - just re-writing the entire line, as opposed to the last x characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could clear the console and then write the new output.

Comment: I think this solution doesn't scale well if the console app becomes more involved; you'd have to keep a buffer of what to print and reprint many times.