# c# removing whole text when it is displayed

Tags: c#, string, text

I would like to ask you for help. How i am supposed to remove whole text when i press a button, (for instance 1). Is there a way to do that?

The problem is on **c# console application**

Comment: Remove whole text from console window?

Comment: Overwrite it with blanks!

Comment: Did you see the [Console.SetCursorPosition function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  char c = Console.     ReadKey().KeyChar ;
```

Capture the key and overwrite it with blank

Answer (score 0):

With Console.Clear() you can remove every Text from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Console.Clear();
```

[to clear the console window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.console.clear(v=vs.110).aspx). This removes *the whole text* from the console window.

Or [send a delete character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195692/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-character-that-has-just-been-written-using-console-wr) to move the cursor backwards:

```
 Console.Write("\b");
```

The you can overwrite it with another character.