# Overwriting Console line with various length texts

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display percentages of loading in the same place

and I found solution on that

```
Console.Write($"\r{ (double) (i+1) * 100 / list.Count }% - {text}");
```

but after the percentage I'd want to display some text which has **different** lengths e.g something between 20-40 characters

The problem with this approach is that if "new" line is shorter than "previous" then some part of "previous" text still remains there.

I managed to write 'hack' which overwrites current line with spaces (clears it) and then writes my line

```
Console.Write($"\r                                                                                                             ");
Console.Write($"\r{ (double) (i+1) * 100 / list.Count }% - {text}");
```

Is there an better solution to do that?

Comment: If you know the length of the previous text you can write as many Backspace characters (`\b`) to the console and the do the `Console.Write`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195807/2137237

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is generally with

```
var stringOfLengthMaxWithSpacestoLeft = yourString.PadLeft(MaxStringLength, ' ');
```

or

```
var stringOfLengthMaxWithSpacestoRight = yourString.PadRight(MaxStringLength, ' ');
```

If you want to clear the line, all you have to do is use the backspace character and then overwrite with with the same length, i.e.

```
for (var i = 0; i++; i < MaxStringLength) 
    Console.Write("\b");
```

Then you can start writing again.